# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTFBLoginButton" was not found in the UIManger

Tags: react-native

```
<LoginButton/>
```

I have installed the `react-native-fbsdk` am still
getting this error when i use LoginButton in my see error link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/msU6M.jpg

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124766/how-to-fix-invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rctfbloginbutton-was

Comment: mine is windows not mac am using "react-native": "^0.62.1",